# Конвертация json строки в js объект

Tags: php, javascript, json

В php файле есть массив который передается так:`echo json_encode($new_content);`.
Его принимает функция, заданная при успешном выполнении AJAX запроса. Но почему то вместо того что бы нормально конвертироваться с json строки в js объект я получаю `[object Object]`. Подскажите почему

Вот `php`

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$time = date('H:i:s');

$file = "../data/messages.json";
$json_content = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

$content = array();

if(is_array($json_content)) {
    $content = $json_content;
}

if (!empty($message)) {
    $content[] = array("time" => $time, "user" => $user, "message"  => $message);

    $new_content = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($content as $key => $id) {
        $new_id = $id;
        $new_id['id'] = $i;
        $new_content[$id['user'] ] = $new_id;
        $i++;
    }
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($new_content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),FILE_APPEND);

}
echo json_encode($new_content);
?>
```

Вот JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#easyForm').submit(function(){
        var text = $('#text').val();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'php/chat_script.php',
            data : {
                message:text
            },
            success: function(arr) {
                arr = $.parseJSON(arr);
                $('#time').html(arr.time);
                $('#name').html(arr.user);
                $('#message').html(arr.message);
            }
        });
        return  false;
    });
});
```

Вот содержание массив

`{"qwe":{"time":"20:57:55","user":"qwe","message":"qwe","id":0}}`

Answer (score 0):

И будет вам счастье, а еще есть такая штука как `arr = JSON.stringify(arr)`

Вариант 2 более правильный

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($new_content);
?>


$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('#easyForm').submit(function(e){
        var text = $('#text').val();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'php/chat_script.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data : {
                message:text
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#time').html(data.time);
                $('#name').html(data.user);
                $('#message').html(data.message);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали в опциях `$.ajax` тип ожидаемого ответа. jQuery очень старается передать в обработчик `success`, то, что по мнению библиотеки, Вы хотели возвратить. В данном случае, это правильно квалифицировано как текст формата JSON, который уже преобразован в js объект, который и подан параметром в `success`.

Строку

```
arr = $.parseJSON(arr);
```

нужно убрать.

*Update*

Массива я не вижу, а вижу объект с одним свойством `qwe`, у которого, есть свойства: `time`, `user`, `message` и `id`

```
$('#time').html(arr.qwe.time);
$('#name').html(arr.qwe.user);
$('#message').html(arr.qwe.message);
```

Comment: Смотрите, я прикрепил к сообщению  то, что содержится в массиве на выходе. Как вы поняли после  этого мне нужно в отдельные элементы на странице html поместить значения с этого массива(для каждого элемента определенное значение).Но это не происходит